# Microsoft Access VBA Event Procedure On Timer Error

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook

I am working on adding a auto email function to a existing database. I have a OnTimer event that calls for a email notification based on the number a days that a item is due. Every time I try to save the code, I get the following error:

[image]

The database is a Access 2002-2003 file, so I am not sure if this is a factor as to why the application is not working, or if I am missing something else. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Code for the Form:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Form_Timer()
Me.TextTime.Value = Format(Time, "HH:mm:ss AM/PM")
Static iCount As Integer
    If iCount = 60 Then
        Me.TimerInterval = 0
        Call modAutoEmail("SELECT * FROM qNMReport3D")
    If Me.TimerInterval = 0 Then
    Me.TimerInterval = 125
    End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Code for the email module:

```
Option Explicit

Function GenerateEmail(mysql As String)
Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmailItem As MailItem
Dim MyEmpName As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mysql)
If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF
    If IsNull(rs!Email) Then
            rs.MoveNext
    Else
        If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
            Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
        End If
        With oEmailItem
                    MyEmpName = DLookup("[FullName]", "tEmployee", "[ID] = " & rs!EmpName)
                    .To = rs!Email
                    .Subject = "3D due in 1 days Reminder"
                    .Body = "Task ID: " & rs!taskid & vbCr & _
                            "Task Name: " & rs!TaskName & vbCr & _
                            "Employee: " & MyEmpName & vbCr & _
                            "3D Due: " & rs!DueDate & vbCr & _
                            "This email is auto generated from Corporate Database. Please Do Not Reply."
                            
                            .Send
                            rs.Edit
                            rs!dateemailsent = Date
                            rs.Update
        End With
        Set oEmailItem = Nothing
        Set oOutlook = Nothing
        rs.MoveNext
    End If
    Loop
    Else
    End If
    rs.Close
Exit Function:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: It looks as if you had imported the form resp. report from another database. Create the form resp. report within your database. It should be possible to save it. Only then you can add the VBA code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you try to call the module name:

```
Call modAutoEmail("SELECT * FROM qNMReport3D")
```

This doesn't work, I don't know though if this triggers this funky error message.

You need to call the function:

```
Call GenerateEmail("SELECT * FROM qNMReport3D")
```

Also in your Timer function, you never increase `iCount`, so the email will never be sent.

`.TimerInterval` is in milliseconds, so if it *would* work, it would be called every 60/8 = 7.5 seconds, which is probably not what you want.